# Simple learning to rank algorithm with regression and pairwise logit loss

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

Given you have a data sets that has a document features and corresponding query features. each query will have multiple documents in which you have to rank each document for each corresponding query by their relevance. I conceptually understand how the pairwise ranking loss function with logits and regression can be applied here for simplicity but I'm sure how to implement in code in pyspark. given there is the structure between query and document, multiple docs belong to one query and we want to rank within them not across queries. Hope to see if there's any simple example code with toy data set or if there is some walk through tutorials.

I tried tensorflow TFR library but it was a bit more complicated than I expected I didn't manage to prepare data in a way that I wanted or build a model that can handle data with such doc,query structure.
any help will be very much appreciated.

I tried tensorflow TFR library but it was a bit more complicated than I expected I didn't manage to prepare data in a way that I wanted or build a model that can handle data with such doc,query structure.